# Grails URL Mapping question

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.2.1.  I want to set up this mapping ...

http://localhost:8080/context-path/mediaproxy

So I added this to my URLMappings.groovy file ...

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
      ‰name mediaproxy: "/mediaproxy" {
          controller = "SocialMediaCacheProxy"
          action = "index"
      }
      "/"(view:"/index")
      "500"(view:'/error')
    }

}
```

However, I'm getting a 404 when I visit the above URL.  Here is how I set up my controller

```
class SocialMediaCacheProxyController {

    def index = {
        if (params.dumpAll != null) {

        } else if (params.url != null) {
            doCacheTransport(params, response); 
        }   // if
    }

...
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

There are is some weird character in front of your named mapping (‰) and your controller name should be lowercase on the first character so that it points to SocialMediaCacheProxyController.

If you don't need a named mapping the following mapping would do the trick for you:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/mediaproxy"(controller:"socialMediaCacheProxy", action:"index")
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be some problem with your question formatting but I would expect the url mapping to look like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
      "/mediaproxy" {
          controller = "SocialMediaCacheProxy"
          action = "index"
      }
      "/"(view:"/index")
      "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```